# *ngFor not displaying data

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

component.ts file

```
posts= [];
  constructor( private http:HttpClient) { 
    http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
    .subscribe(response=>{
      this.posts.push(response)
      console.log(this.posts)
    });
  }
```

in HTML file

```
<ul class="list-group">
  <li 
    *ngFor="let post of posts"
    class="list-group-item">{{post.title}}</li>
</ul>
```

I can see the data from array if I consoled but for some reason the *ngFor only displays one blank container.

Comment: What does your console shows for `response` data?

Comment: I think your code should be this.posts = response, not this.posts.push(response);

Comment: The response from the URL is an array. At the moment you're having an array of an array: `[[{}, {}, ... ]]`. You need to assign the array to the variable instead of pushing it: `this.posts = response`.

Comment: i checked the type of response from URL and its an object.

Comment: It is not an object, it is an array.

Answer (score 1):

The response of `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts` is array of objects

```
[
  {
   userId: 1,
   id: 1,
   title: "sunt aut facere repellat",
   body: "quia et suscipit suscipit recusandae consequuntur"
  },
 {
   userId: 1,
   id: 2,
   title: "qui est esse",
   body: "est rerum tempore vitae sequi"
 },
]
```

so instead of pushing array of object within array, all you need to assign the response.

Create a posts interface instead of using `any[]` type casting

```
export interface IPosts = {
  userId: number;
  id: number;
  title: string;
  body: string;
}
```

Now fetch data from end point

```
posts: IPosts[]; // notice the type instead of any we have proper type.

constructor(private http:HttpClient) { 

const url = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts';
http.get(url).subscribe((response: IPosts[]) => this.posts = response)}
```

And in template just iterate the result.

```
<ul class="list-group" *ngIf="posts.length"> <=== for safe side you could use if condition only show if posts are available.
  <li 
    *ngFor="let post of posts"
    class="list-group-item">{{post.title}}</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

The response from `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts` is an array of objects. But you are using `Array.push()` to add items to `posts` array. So the `posts` array will have only 1 item (which is array of objects) and that item will not have `title` property.

Try doing this:

```
  posts = [];

  constructor( private http:HttpClient) { 
    http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
    .subscribe(response=>{
      this.posts = response
      console.log(this.posts)
    });
  }
```

---

You can also use [`async`](https://angular.io/guide/observables-in-angular#async-pipe) pipe in this situation

```
 posts = this.http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts');

 constructor( private http:HttpClient) {}



<ul class="list-group">
  <li *ngFor="let post of posts | async" class="list-group-item"> 
     {{post.title}}
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: its giving an error:  
The 'Object' type is assignable to very few other types. Did you mean to use the 'any' type instead?
  Type 'Object' is missing the following properties from type 'any[]': length, pop, push, concat, and 26 more.

Comment: You can try type casting:  `.subscribe((response: any[]) =>{this.posts = response });`

Comment: Thanks alot every one. I got the expected output after typecasting the response

Comment: @WaseemAbbas `any[]` typecast not recommended

Comment: @HarunYilmaz checkout my answer that is the proper way to use type instead of any etc.

Comment: @HarunYilmaz feel free to upvote my answer if you like the approach :)

Comment: @KamranKhatti I misread the part `any[]` :) You're right.